# UITableView Header / Footer is displaying

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way / method of know if or when a table's header of footer will be displayed? Much like the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method for cells, but for section headers/footers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomment you to use following [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)'s following methods:

```
– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
```

There are a lot more convenient methods in there, have a look!

---

About knowing when the view will appear:

You can return the desired view in `viewForHeader/FooterInSecion`. That view's controller has it's own `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` in which you can do further code execution.

Comment: Thanks, I am using these to display them. But I need to know when they are actually being shown on the table. Like in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath you can say this row is will be displayed, I want to do it for section headers/footers.

Comment: these methods also supply a `section` - you could do custom initialization using that `section` integer: `if(section == 0) { //first section initialization } if(section == 1) { // do nothing }` and so on

Comment: Ah yes sorry I should have mentioned that I am using reloadData alot so this gets called frequently, I need to know when the user scrolls to it.